Ошибка при выводе информации об админов беседы при помощи vk_api
newBOT.py:
import vk_api
import utils
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from models import User
from devolper import *
import time



class MyLongPoll(VkBotLongPoll):
    def listen(self):
        while True:
            try:
                for event in self.check():
                    yield event
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)


class VkBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vk = vk_api.VkApi(
            token = 'token')
        self.vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(
            token='token')
        self.vk = self.vk_session.get_api()
        self.longpoll = MyLongPoll(self.vk_session, 214751545)


    def run(self):
        for event in self.longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                msg = event.object.message
                user_id = msg['from_id']
                user = utils.get_user_by_id(user_id)
                user.role = 0
                user.save()
                text = msg['text']
                fwd = self.vk_session.method('messages.getByConversationMessageId', {
                    'conversation_message_ids': msg['conversation_message_id'],
                    'peer_id': msg['peer_id']
                })['items'][0]

                if 'reply_message' in fwd:
                    fwd = fwd['reply_message']
                else:
                    fwd = None

                if user.vk_id == devolper:
                    if fwd:
                        ...
                            elif text == 'админы':

                                user_id = msg['from_id']
                                user_name = self.vk_session.method('users.get', {'user_id': user_id})[0]['first_name']

                                admins = self.vk.messages.getConversationMembers(cmids=msg['conversation_message_id'], peer_id=msg['peer_id'])


                                self.vk_session.method('messages.send', {
                                    'chat_id': msg['peer_id'] - 2000000000,
                                    'message': f'Хорошо, {user_name}!'
                                               f'\nВот список администраторов беседы:'
                                               f'\n \n',
                                    'random_id': 0
                                })

                                for admin in admins['items']:
                                    admin_name = self.vk_session.method('users.get', {'user_id': admin['member_id']})[0]['first_name']
                                    self.vk_session.method('messages.send', {
                                        'chat_id': msg['peer_id'] - 2000000000,
                                        'message': f'{admin_name} - @id{admin["member_id"]}',
                                        'random_id': 0
                                    })
                            ...
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    VkBot().run()

developer.py:
developer = мой айди

utils.py
from models import User
def get_user_by_id(user_id):
try:
    return User().get(vk_id=user_id)
except:
    User(
        vk_id=user_id,
        warns=0,
        role=0
    ).save()
    return User().get(vk_id=user_id)

сама ошибка:
C:\Users\matyt\Downloads\VkBot\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\matyt\Downloads\VkBot\newBOT.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matyt\Downloads\VkBot\newBOT.py", line 180, in <module>
    VkBot().run()
  File "C:\Users\matyt\Downloads\VkBot\newBOT.py", line 138, in run
    admin_name = self.vk_session.method('users.get', {'user_id': admin['member_id']})[0]['first_name']
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1


Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

Какая ошибка? В каком месте? Уточните свой вопрос

@Komdosh поправил, извиняюсь
